# Best place to call RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyItem*?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Updating ListViews with a CursorLoader was a simple way of displaying datas from a DB into UI. Model modifications where propagated to the UI with no extra work, and maybe not so efficiently.

RecyclerView.adapter, gives access to more granularity, allowing for instance to specify the adapter that a particular item was removed.

But, what is the best place to call those preferred methods (notifyItem*), replacing notifyDataSetChanged?

Obviously, the adapter must not observe the contentProvider, otherwise it won't know the nature of the model modification (just as before).

Different patterns could be used, like adding a bus to publish modifications from the provider, creating a singleton model which would hold a reference to the adapter, maybe using presenters (introduced in L), or creating an activity-bound service.

Here is a common use case: a sync process inserts an entry in DB (or a gcm notification is received, which also inserts an entry in DB), then i want UI (if launched) to be updated via a call to notifyItemInserted. Where to place this call?

Thanks.